# ¿Cómo puedo ocultar un div utilizando Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente div:

```
<div class=" d-none d-sm-none d-md-block col-lg-5 work-right-text d-flex align-items-center">
     <div class="px-5 py-5 py-lg-0">
            <h1>Hola</h1>           
     </div>
</div>
```

Quiero que se oculte a partir de dispositivos de 320px, pero solo me oculta a partir de 576px, cómo le puedo hacer para que me oculte para 320px y 576px?

Intente colocar `d-none d-md-block` pero tampoco me funciono

Comment: no existe corte a 320px deberías crearlo.

Comment: te agrego los dos metodos que conosco, tambien te invito al chat cuando tengas dudas: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: hola probaste mi respuesta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hola amigo no existe breakpoint a 320px;

Existen dos formas de resolverlo:

**1. tendrías que crearlo como se indica en este tutorial: [link](https://www.beyondjava.net/how-to-add-a-new-breakpoint-in-bootstrap)**

**antes:**

```
/* taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47753600/3466464 */
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 600px,
  md: 800px,
  lg: 1000px,
  xl: 1280px  // <-- modified!
);

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 600px,
  md: 800px,
  lg: 1000px,
  xl: 1220px  // <-- modified!
);

@import "bootstrap";
```

**Despues:**

```
/* example taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48976550/3466464 */
/* import what we need to override */
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

/* set the overriding variables */
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xxxs: 0,
  xxs: 320px,
  xs: 568px,
  sm: 667px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1440px,
  xxxl: 1600px
)
$container-max-widths: (
  xxxs: 0,
  xxs: 320px,
  xs: 568px,
  sm: 667px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1440px,
  xxxl: 1600px
);

/* override the !default vars with the values we set above */
@import "bootstrap";
```

Todo esto requeriría conocimientos sobre como se compila el CSS de Boostrap `SaSS`.

**2. El otro Método**

Requiere hacer uso de un custom CSS y los Media Querys:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) { 
    .d-xss-block {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

o

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) { 
    .d-xss-none {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Según sea tu necesidad.